# How to walk a nested array of objects and apply a callback function to every element that changes it

Tags: javascript

I need to change the prop key names and prop values of all elements within a nested array of objects

Given this nested object array:

```
const nestedArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "foo",
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "bar",
        children: [
          {
             id: 3,
             name: "baz"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

I want to be able to apply a callback function where I can mutate each object. For this example say I wanted to append all elements name prop with a "1". Or maybe I wanted to change the "name" prop key to "name1".

So after I run a function on it `mutateRecursively(nestedArr, callback)` the array should change to:

```
const nestedArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name1: "foo1",
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name1: "bar1",
        children: [
          {
             id: 3,
             name1: "baz1"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

So basically I need to be able to recursively walk the tree and for each element run a callback function that takes the element as param, does something to it and returns  the new mutated one.

I'm not so interested in the implementation details regarding the callback function, but more like how to walk the tree, and for each element run the callback function that returns a new modified instance of eac element.

Comment: what does not work? please add your try.

Comment: Try this one: https://github.com/substack/js-traverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const nestedArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "foo",
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        name: "bar",
        children: [
          {
             id: 3,
             name: "baz"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
];

function applyCallbackRecursively(array, callback) {
  return Array.isArray(array) ? array.map(({ children, ...item }) => ({ children: applyCallbackRecursively(children, callback), ...callback(item) })) : array;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Only thing I had to add was `array && ` before the `array.map` part